# Converting long list of if/else

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

In order to convert a code such as:

```
Company company = new Company();  
if(currentToken.equals("employee_list")) {  
   company.setEmployees((ArrayList<Employee> parseEmployees(reader));  
}    
else if(currentToken.equals("contractor_list")) {  
   company.setContractors((ArrayList<Contractor> parseContractors(reader));  
}    
else if(currentToken.equals("legal_name")) {  
   company.setLegalName((String)reader.nextString());  
}    
else if(currentToken.equals("profit")) {  
   company.setLegalName(Double.parseDouble((String)reader.nextString()));    
} ...etc
```

I.e long list of if/else reading from a stream and populating the object I did the following:

```
public interface CustomSetter<T> {  
  void setToObject(T o, Reader r);  
}

HashMap<String, CustomSetter> setters = new HashMap<>();  
setters.put("employee_list", new CustomSetter<Company>() { 
     public void setObject(Company company, Reader reader) {  
        company.setEmployees((ArrayList<Employee> parseEmployees(reader));   
     }  
 });  

setters.put("contractor_list", new CustomSetter<Company>() { 
     public void setObject(Company company, Reader reader) {  
        company.setContractors((ArrayList<Contractor> parseContractors(reader));   
     }  
 });
```

etc.
Effectively doing:

```
setters.get(currentToken).setObject(company, reader);
```

So now I have all these initialized in my hashmap.
What do you think of this approach? Can it be improved?

Comment: "Code such as" and "if I did the following" is too hypothetical for review, especially when the code contains an error. Please ensure that you are posting working code from a real project, and title your question according to the task that your code accomplishes (see [ask]).

Comment: @200_success:In what way does the typo error make the post coded not clear? Why is  changing one coding style to another not accepted as a post?

Comment: On Code Review, we look at every detail of the code you posted. If the code contains critical errors like `company.setLegalName(…)`, then it's all just pseudocode. What are we to review?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that `Company` has e setter method signature as `setEmployees(List employees)` or `setEmployees(Arraylist employees)` or some `?` wildcard setter, since it accepts as parameter `List<Employee>` and `List<Contractor>`.

I would also assume that `Employee` and `Contractor` extend one another or the same super class.

In that case, I don't see the benefit of creating such a custom generic setter. Instead I would use the same setter, and mitigate the type identification in the parsing method: `company.setEmployees(parseFromReader(currentToken, reader))`
and have the `List<Employee> parseFromReader(currentToken, reader)` worry about the specific instance type, since I assume also most of the information to be parsed would be the same (if the classes extend the same super class).

Comment: But how would I know that I should call the `setEmployees`? That depends on the current token. And so we end up to the code I originally posted. Unless I missed your point.

Comment: Read again your original code, something confuses me, you call the same `setEmployees`method for the `employee_list` and `contractor_list` token, in the first approach. Then in the second approach you call a different method on `company` in each case...

Comment: You are right. It was a typo. I updated the OP

Comment: Also the contractors and employees are not related classed

Comment: in that case, you could create a list of overloaded methods say `setValue`, ex `setValue(Arraylist<Employee> employees)`, `setValue(Arraylist<Contractor> contractos)` and let the runtime choose the specific method but i think in real code scenario, you could have more setters with the same parameter type.

Comment: But in generics the parameterized type is replaced anyway right?

Comment: I didn't say generics, rather overloaded `setValue` methods on your Company class. So you could call `setValue(employees)` where employees is of type `Arraylist<Employee>` thus calling the proper setter.

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying. In `Arraylist<Employee>` the `<Employee>` is erased so we only have `Arraylist`. Right?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotOverload